# So really, HOW do you make a facebook iframe now?

Tags: facebook, iframe

Facebook changes their API constantly, and trust me I've tried googling but everything is out of date. Even stuff from 3 months ago is out of date. The last major change was Oct 1st as in requiring SSL.

I just want to make a fan page iframe where it has a fan gate.

1. Wildfire app seemed easiest until I realized it doesnt allow ANYTHING as far as html goes (no background urls? give me a break)
2. I tried creating a new app but I dont have an SSL certificate. I'm thinking about creating a self signed one. will this work?

How do i integrate a fan gate into option #2?

Comment: Whatever server you are hosting this on will need a real, paid for non-expired SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://social-server.com/ to make a psuedo-certificated version of you app, works fine with facebook.